# install magento 2 windows server 2019

Tags: php, magento2

Im trying to install Magento 2 on a windows server 2019.

i have installed PHP Version 7.2.26, mysql, phpmyadmin.

When i run setup on magento 2 there is 2 extension that show error.

> ```
> PHP Extension xsl 
> PHP Extension sockets
> ```

In my php.ini i have

> ```
> extension=php_xsl.dll
> extension=php_sockets.dll
> ```

and the 2 dll files in ext, but stil i get this error.

And after uninstalled XAMPP i cant access phpmyadmin.

need help.

Comment: What are the errors you see? Did you install PHP, MySQL, phpMyAdmin and XAMPP separately? In that case, you probably have multiple PHP versions.

Comment: i install PHP, MySQL, phpMyAdmin and XAMPP separately, i have manage to fix the phpmyadmin problem.

Comment: In that case you have two installations of PHP. XAMPP already includes PHP. This means you also have two `php.ini` files. Make sure you enabled the extension in the correct file.

Comment: I have mine php.ini in C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.2, and the right extension is enable.